# Custom Tabbar resize

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbaritem

I have a problem with my custom Tabbar while selecting the size of button appear smaller than the old state

```
btnImage =[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_2_89x46"];  
btnImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_2h_209x109"];
btn2 =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn2.frame=CGRectMake(66, 274, 89, 46);
[btn2 setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn2 setBackgroundImage:btnImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to give proper frame to tabbar.If tabbar is given at the bottom of the view then move it up.you can use uitabbaritems which are predefined.

Comment: can you give an example or any link?